# Can a pycel object be saved as an Excel Workbook

Tags: python, pycel

After parsing Excel file to Python and evaluating the workbook using pycel, can the pycel object be saved as an Excel file maintaining all original formatting, etc? I.e. only values need to be updated.

Comment: Pycel is a small python library that can translate an Excel spreadsheet into executable python code which can be run independently of Excel.

You need to use https://datatofish.com/export-dataframe-to-excel/ Pandas like library to export the data you parsed using pycel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TL;DR

No, you cannot save a pycel object back into Excel.

#### Why not?

The basic problem is that pycel is based on openpyxl.  Openpyxl is used to read (and write if needed) Excel spreadsheets.  However, while openpyxl has the computed values available for formula cells for a workbook it read in, it does not really allow those computed values to be saved back into a workbook it writes.  It doesn't really make sense to save a different computed value for a formula cell, since the cell's value will be recomputed once it is opened back up in Excel.

While it is true that pycel has the information available to properly populate a new value when the workbook is written, it evidently is not a use case that was important to the openpyxl authors or contributors.

<sub>Please note that the openpyxl maintainers gladly took pull requests to make it run better with pycel.  It seems likely they would be open to discussing a PR for writing values into workbooks.</sub>